# Angular auxiliary routes works locally but not when deployed

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

I have a problem with direct access to a Auxiliary route. When I am accessing /home/(post:12) locally everything work just fine. But when I am trying to do it when app is deployed to github pages, wild 404 appears.

Basically the auxiliary route is loading popup modal.

```
<router-outlet name="post"></router-outlet>
```

Here is Router Module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: ShellComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':postId',
            component: PostEntryComponent,
            outlet: 'post'
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'home',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ]
      },
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'}
    ])
```

I want to make it work like on local server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would that help?

```js
// Excerpt app-routing.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```